# Unable to display information from multiple data models in AWS Amplify UI component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify and Amplify Studio to build a simple web app. I have created two Data Models, Booking and Provider. Using the UI Library visual editor, I am able to select multiple component properties and set these to the relevant data models but the issue arrises once I pull these components down locally and attempt to display this information in my react app.

[image: Data Model]

I have created some test data in amplify and use the following code to render the data:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Booking, Provider } from '../models';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { DataStore } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Bookings } from '../ui-components';

function App() {

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState([])

  const getBookings = async () => {
    const data = await DataStore.query(Booking)
    setBookings(data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBookings()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {bookings.map(booking => <Bookings booking={booking} provider={booking.Provider} key=booking.id}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem arrises where I am trying to display providerName from the Provider Data Model. According to the guide here by an AWS Amplify developer here: https://youtu.be/ea6qrUMwqEo?t=751, I should be able to pass my Booking model to my Bookings Component and then I should be able to pass the Provider model the booking.Provider due to the relationship between the two models.

I have used console.log to print out each individual booking component and this below is the result.

[image: console.log(booking)]

I suspect the issue is because the booking.Provider data model is contained within a Promise and therefore it is unable to access it properly?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This was due to breaking changes in v5 of aws-amplify. Downgrading versions resolved this for me.